# Getting the number of pages of pdf on aws using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I would like to count the number of pages in a pdf that is stored online (on aws s3) but I can't figure out how to do this in javascript.

So basically what I'm looking for is a function, f:url->int, that takes a url and returns the #pages of the pdf at that url.

I have already looked at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js but to me it seems like this is for node.js (i.e. a server side app) and i'm building a client application.

Hope some of you are able to help me.

Kind regards Morten

Comment: According to [the docs](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#is-there-a-pre-built-version-pdfjs-available) and following [this link](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) to view the sample pdf, and inspecting the loaded .js files, this seems a perfectly client-based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its super easy, use PDF.JS and do the following:

```
PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf').then(function(pdf) {
      alert('this document has ' + pdf.numPages);
});
```